# Determinant of a complex matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Is there a way to calculate the determinant of a complex matrix?

```
F4<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1i,-1,-1i,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1i,-1,1i),nrow=4)
det(F4)
Error in determinant.matrix(x, logarithm = TRUE, ...) : 
  determinant not currently defined for complex matrices

library(Matrix)
 determinant(Matrix(F4))
Error in Matrix(F4) : 
  complex matrices not yet implemented in Matrix package
Error in determinant(Matrix(F4)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'determinant'
```

Comment: With the **EigenR** package this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

If you use  prod(eigen(F4)$values) 
I'd recommend
  `prod(eigen(F4, only.values=TRUE)$values)`
instead.

Note that the `qr()` is advocated to use **iff** you are only interested in the
absolute value or rather `Mod()` :

```
 prod(abs(Re(diag(qr(x)$qr))))
```

gives the `Mod(determinant(x))`
{In  X = QR,  |det(Q)|=1  and the diagonal of R is real (in R at least).}

BTW: Did you note the caveat

> Often, computing the determinant is
>   *not* what you should be doing
>        to solve a given problem.

on the  help(determinant)  page ?

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the characteristic polynomial of a matrix A splits into linear factors, then det(A) is the product of the eigenvalues of A, and you can use eigen value functions like [this](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/r_v2.9.2/lib/R/library/base/html/eigen.html) to work around your problem. I suspect you'll still want something better, but this might be a start.

Comment: For the time being I also use prod(eigen(F4)$values)